# Liquibase NoSuchMethodError with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

When running my Liquibase setup I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  liquibase.database.Database.escapeTableName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

I really cannot tell what is wrong with my initial schema file, can anyone with more experience help me spot the errors? If I had to guess it's most likely something from the file  I have to change so that it's compatible with SQL Server, but I cannot, for the life of me find what is causing the exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql,h2"/>
    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>
    <property name="now" value="GETDATE()" dbms="mssql"/>

    <changeSet id="00000000000000" author="jhipster" dbms="postgresql">
        <createSequence sequenceName="hibernate_sequence" startValue="1000" incrementBy="1"/>
    </changeSet>

    <!--
        JHipster core tables.
        The initial schema has the '00000000000001' id, so that it is over-written if we re-generate it.
    -->
    <changeSet id="00000000000001" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="JHI_USER">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="login" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints unique="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="password" type="varchar(100)"/>
            <column name="first_name" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="last_name" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="email" type="varchar(100)">
                <constraints unique="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="activated" type="boolean" valueBoolean="false">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="lang_key" type="varchar(5)"/>
            <column name="activation_key" type="varchar(20)"/>
            <column name="reset_key" type="varchar(20)"/>
            <column name="created_by" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="created_date" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="${now}">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="reset_date" type="timestamp">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="last_modified_by" type="varchar(50)"/>
            <column name="last_modified_date" type="timestamp"/>
        </createTable>

        <createIndex indexName="idx_user_login"
            tableName="JHI_USER"
            unique="true">
            <column name="login" type="varchar(50)"/>
        </createIndex>

        <createIndex indexName="idx_user_email"
            tableName="JHI_USER"
            unique="true">
            <column name="email" type="varchar(100)"/>
        </createIndex>

        <createTable tableName="JHI_AUTHORITY">
            <column name="name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="JHI_USER_AUTHORITY">
            <column name="user_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="authority_name" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>

        <addPrimaryKey columnNames="user_id, authority_name" tableName="JHI_USER_AUTHORITY"/>

        <createTable tableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_TOKEN">
            <column name="series" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="user_id" type="bigint"/>
            <column name="token_value" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="token_date" type="date"/>
            <column name="ip_address" type="varchar(39)"/>
            <column name="user_agent" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="authority_name"
                                 baseTableName="JHI_USER_AUTHORITY"
                                 constraintName="fk_authority_name"
                                 referencedColumnNames="name"
                                 referencedTableName="JHI_AUTHORITY"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="user_id"
                                 baseTableName="JHI_USER_AUTHORITY"
                                 constraintName="fk_user_id"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="JHI_USER"/>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="user_id"
                                 baseTableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_TOKEN"
                                 constraintName="fk_user_persistent_token"
                                 referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="JHI_USER"/>

        <ext:loadData encoding="UTF-8"
                  file="config/liquibase/users.csv"
                  separator=";"
                  tableName="JHI_USER" identityInsertEnabled="true">
            <column name="activated" type="boolean"/>
            <column name="created_date" type="timestamp"/>
        </ext:loadData>
        <dropDefaultValue tableName="JHI_USER" columnName="created_date" columnDataType="datetime"/>

        <ext:loadData encoding="UTF-8"
                      file="config/liquibase/authorities.csv"
                      separator=";"
                      tableName="JHI_AUTHORITY"
                      identityInsertEnabled="true" />

        <ext:loadData encoding="UTF-8"
                      file="config/liquibase/users_authorities.csv"
                      separator=";"
                      tableName="JHI_USER_AUTHORITY"
                      identityInsertEnabled="true" />

        <createTable tableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT">
            <column name="event_id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="principal" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="event_date" type="timestamp"/>
            <column name="event_type" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT_DATA">
            <column name="event_id" type="bigint">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="value" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>
        <addPrimaryKey columnNames="event_id, name" tableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT_DATA"/>

        <createIndex indexName="idx_persistent_audit_event"
                     tableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT"
                     unique="false">
            <column name="principal" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="event_date" type="timestamp"/>
        </createIndex>

        <createIndex indexName="idx_persistent_audit_event_data"
                     tableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT_DATA"
                     unique="false">
            <column name="event_id" type="bigint"/>
        </createIndex>

        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="event_id"
                                 baseTableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT_DATA"
                                 constraintName="FK_event_persistent_audit_event_data"
                                 referencedColumnNames="event_id"
                                 referencedTableName="JHI_PERSISTENT_AUDIT_EVENT"/>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Here is the error full stack trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  liquibase.database.Database.escapeTableName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>
> ```
>     at liquibase.ext.mssql.sqlgenerator.InsertGenerator.generateSql(InsertGenerator.java:37)
>     at liquibase.ext.mssql.sqlgenerator.InsertGenerator.generateSql(InsertGenerator.java:18)
>     at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorChain.generateSql(SqlGeneratorChain.java:30)
>     at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorFactory.generateSql(SqlGeneratorFactory.java:208)
>     at liquibase.executor.AbstractExecutor.applyVisitors(AbstractExecutor.java:23)
>     at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.access$500(JdbcExecutor.java:36)
>     at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:304)
>     at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
>     at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
>     at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1227)
>     at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1210)
>     at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:550)
>     at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:43)
>     at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73)
>     at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:200)
>     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353)
>     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:317)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
>     ... 107 more
> ```

---

**Edits after bounty:**

I am running this with a Spring boot configuration, running using [jHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/).

My database is configured here:

**Spring boot Application.java**

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Initializes winserver.
     * <p/>
     * Spring profiles can be configured with a program arguments --spring.profiles.active=your-active-profile
     * <p/>
     * <p>
     * You can find more information on how profiles work with JHipster on <a href="http://jhipster.github.io/profiles.html">http://jhipster.github.io/profiles.html</a>.
     * </p>
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() throws IOException {
        if (env.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
            log.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration");
        } else {
            log.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
            Collection activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
            if (activeProfiles.contains("dev") && activeProfiles.contains("prod")) {
                log.error("You have misconfigured your application! " +
                    "It should not run with both the 'dev' and 'prod' profiles at the same time.");
            }
            if (activeProfiles.contains("prod") && activeProfiles.contains("fast")) {
                log.error("You have misconfigured your application! " +
                    "It should not run with both the 'prod' and 'fast' profiles at the same time.");
            }
            if (activeProfiles.contains("dev") && activeProfiles.contains("cloud")) {
                log.error("You have misconfigured your application! " +
                    "It should not run with both the 'dev' and 'cloud' profiles at the same time.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method, used to run the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);
        SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
        addDefaultProfile(app, source);
        addLiquibaseScanPackages();
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
        log.info("Access URLs:\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
            "Local: \t\thttp://127.0.0.1:{}\n\t" +
            "External: \thttp://{}:{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
            env.getProperty("server.port"),
            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
            env.getProperty("server.port"));

    }

    /**
     * If no profile has been configured, set by default the "dev" profile.
     */
    private static void addDefaultProfile(SpringApplication app, SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source) {
        if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active") &&
                !System.getenv().containsKey("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE")) {

            app.setAdditionalProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the liquibases.scan.packages to avoid an exception from ServiceLocator.
     */
    private static void addLiquibaseScanPackages() {
        System.setProperty("liquibase.scan.packages", Joiner.on(",").join(
            "liquibase.change", "liquibase.database", "liquibase.parser",
            "liquibase.precondition", "liquibase.datatype",
            "liquibase.serializer", "liquibase.sqlgenerator", "liquibase.executor",
            "liquibase.snapshot", "liquibase.logging", "liquibase.diff",
            "liquibase.structure", "liquibase.structurecompare", "liquibase.lockservice",
            "liquibase.ext", "liquibase.changelog"));
    }
}
```

**DatabaseConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.winserver.repository")
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    private Environment env;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(env, "spring.datasource.");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @ConditionalOnMissingClass(name = "com.winserver.config.HerokuDatabaseConfiguration")
    @Profile("!" + Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null && propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName") == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    " cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                    Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"));
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(propertyResolver.getProperty("url"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", propertyResolver.getProperty("serverName"));
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("url", propertyResolver.getProperty("url"));
        }
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", propertyResolver.getProperty("username"));
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", propertyResolver.getProperty("password"));

        //MySQL optimizations, see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration
        if ("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", propertyResolver.getProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", propertyResolver.getProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", propertyResolver.getProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048"));
        }
        if (metricRegistry != null) {
            config.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        }
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts("development, production");
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST)) {
            if ("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"))) {
                liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
                log.warn("Using '{}' profile with H2 database in memory is not optimal, you should consider switching to" +
                    " MySQL or Postgresql to avoid rebuilding your database upon each start.", Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST);
            } else {
                liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
            }
        } else {
            log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        }
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    public Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module() {
        return new Hibernate4Module();
    }
}
```

**application-dev.yml**

```
server:
    port: 8080

spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
    datasource:
        driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        dataSourceClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource
        url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test
        databaseName:
        serverName:
        username: user
        password: supersecretpassword
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true

    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
        database: SQLServer
        openInView: false
        show_sql: true
        generate-ddl: false
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
            naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    messages:
        cache-seconds: 1
    thymeleaf:
        mode: XHTML
        cache: false

metrics:
    jmx.enabled: true
    spark:
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 9999
    graphite:
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 2003
        prefix: winserver

cache:
    timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
    ehcache:
        maxBytesLocalHeap: 16M
```

Comment: What version of liquibase are you using?

Comment: Using Liquibase 3.3.2, liquibase-slf4j1.2.1, and liquibase-hibernate4 3.5

Comment: Check if all the liquibase jars are in the correct place, and there is no CLASSPATH or JAVA_PATH pointing to a previous version to liquibase. Also, make sure you are using the correct Java version, just in case.

Comment: It will also help if you can provide your command line for invoking liquibase.

Comment: Dunno why the SQL Server tag was removed, I am not using PostgreSQL for this, the initial configuration file only happens to have PostgreSQL information. Readding the tag. 

@HingeSight I am not using the command line, I'm running Liquibase from a Spring boot configuration.

I can provide more documentation as to what I'm doing, making the question a lot more unreadable, so I'll do so.

Comment: As mentioned in the edit, if the PostgreSQL information is what is screwing up the SQL Server run then if anyone can provide a working example of the above file running properly with SQL server in this context I'm more than willing to award the bounty with just that.

Comment: @Eric, my apologies for the tag edit. I should have investigated deeper. Your question seems to be tightly connected with the integration of liquibase and mssql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check your liquidbase configuration and especially the jar file responsible for mssql integration. The mssql integration available on liquidbase git repository is not compatible with liquibase 3.X and should throw NoSuchMethodError.

See https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/display/CONTRIB/MS+SqlServer+Extensions for newer integrations.

As alternative, try setting identityInsertEnabled='false' in all your loadData.

Edit:
After @Eric posted his resolution as a comment below, I would stress again that a previous and obsolate version of liquidbase-mssql.jar is maybe lurking somewhere on the classpath.

Comment: I need the identity insert, I use it to insert the initial server data. I checked and I am using the extension version 1.2.0, trying to update my extension version to 1.4 which seems to be the latest in their git fails. It appears to not be public? Do you have a link, can't find it at all in maven repository.

Comment: Trying with: https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.github.sabomichal|liquibase-mssql|1.4|    com.github.sabomichal - liquibase-mssql

Comment: @Eric, That is weird: https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.github.sabomichal|liquibase-mssql|1.4| looks exactly what you need. How about, as a test, just find the jar in your local file system and manually replace with liquidbase-mssql-1.4.jar downloaded from the maven cental link above. And then see. Also make sure there is no older version of it.
Not using identityInsert is still possible, but awkward to embarassment: do not use autoincrement="true" (and various indices, checks, etc.) for the columns when creating. Add them after data import. At least this _may_ speed up the import.

Comment: This led me down a rabbit hole where I had to change a few other things and I finally managed to solve everything!

I'll write a blog post and add it to the main post later on. Thank you so much HingeSight. Enjoy the bounty, you saved me.

What mainly led to this being usable was indeed changing from the old mssql extension for liquibase (1.2) to the newest.

Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Bounty will be awarded in ~5 hours